# Сыпется или сыплется

Tags: лексика

Как правильно говорить "сыпется" или "сыплется"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В принципе, в русском языке есть обе формы. Однако форма без Л (сыпется, трепется) являются просторечными и не соответствуют нормам грамотной литературной речи. Поэтому правильно будет все-таки *"сыплется", "щиплется", "треплется"*.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить Лопатину, современные нормы допускают употребление форм без Л по крайней мере для некоторых подобных глаголов:
*сыпать, сыплю, сыплет, сыплют и сыпет, сыпят, пов. сыпь

щипать, щиплю, щиплет, щиплют и щипет, щипят; также -аю, -ает (защемлять; рвать)

трепать, треплю, треплет, треплют и трепет, трепят, пов. трепли и трепи*

Не знаю, есть ещё подобные?

Comment: В каких-то словарях "колеблю" и "колебаю" считают допустимыми. Ну и несловарное "дремаю" распространено в народе шире, чем "дремлю", наверное.

Answer (score -1):

КапаЛ - капЛет. Если в глаголе прошлого времени есть Л, то эта буква сохраняется в том же глаголе настоящего времени.

Comment: В большинстве глаголов прошедшего времени есть -л-. И что, во всех них "сохраняется Л"?